# How to calculate difference between two times in ionic using typescript?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

```html
 this.authService.drawgraph(id).subscribe(data => {
          if (data.success) {
            this.new._id = this.todosData[i]._id;
            this.new.sdate = this.todosData[i].sdate;
            this.new.stime = this.todosData[i].stime;
            this.new.etime = this.todosData[i].etime;
```

this is how I'm getting the time stored (stime and etime) in my database. now I want to calculate the difference between these two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do this: (I assume that etime stands for EndTime and stime stands for StartTime?)

```
this.new.stime = this.todosData[i].stime;
this.new.etime = this.todosData[i].etime;

//if those are ISO strings we simply convert them with new Date()

let difference = new Date(this.new.etime).getTime() - new Date(this.new.stime).getTime();
```

Now you have the difference in milliseconds. You can convert it to seconds/minutes/hours simply dividing it by `1000/60000/3600000`. For example

```
differenceInSeconds = difference/1000;
```

Comment: While trying the solution you Provided, I'm getting this error=>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined

Comment: @Prashant is your `this.new.etime` defined? do `console.log(this.new.etime)`

Comment: 2018-02-02T00:00:00.000Z ,
02:01 ,
03:02                                                                                                                                       
these are the results after console.log(this.new.sdate), console.log(this.new.stime), console.log(this.new.etime)

Comment: are those date objects?

Comment: what about if i want to convert it to day instead of seconds